# How to set Multiple Default fonts according to App Locale(English or Arabic)?

Tags: android, fonts, locale

i'm using this code to Apply my english font to all the app by default

```
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

and i'm using different font in Arabic locale ,is there any way to make multiple default fonts depending on the current locale ?